# how to find a mobile phone via BLE device switch android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am creating an app for BLE device, i have a switch in my BLE device to find my mobile phone, on this scenario when i press a switch i want to play a Audio file which i have stored in raw folder in android studio,

i did this when an app screen is displayed to me or app is opened, it means this works fine on when an app is on foreground, but i want to do this in background, if my mobile is alive or my mobile is not in front of my eye, and when i press a switch from BLE device, i want to play audio file.
how, may i do this ?

i successfully displayed only a toast when i press a switch from BLE to find a mobile ! but not able to perform 
`startService(intent);` to start service for its work execution.
(this service may play a Audio file from local raw folder).

what action do i make for a service, to be executed. ?

Answer (score 0):

To keep the connection open in the first place while your activity is not in the foreground, you need to have a "foreground service" in your app process. Check the Android documentation how to setup such a one. If your app does not have a foreground service, the OS might terminate your app and thereby also kill bluetooth connections it holds.